# Strange error with Symfony-2.8

Tags: debugging, symfony-2.8

I am using Symfony 2.8.18. I was always able to debug the previous error messages I had. I searched on Google for same errors but I did not find anything. Everything worked perfectly before. I restarted my local server and get the following error message:

> Warning: class_implements(): Class �]� does not exist and could not be
>   loaded

Here is a link to the screenshot of the message: [strange bug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4AEc.png).

I deleted the cache by removing the corresponding folders and by using the following command:

```
php app\console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata && php app\console doctrine:cache:clear-query && php app\console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

But it did not solve my problem. I do not know how to understand this error message.

Do you have any ideas on how to debug the code?

Comment: Hi, can you edit your post and show what the file: `app/AppKernel.php` contains? I think that is where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not change anything but it seems one or several files were corrupted. The solution was to:

1. Remove the vendor folder;
2. Run composer install.

My problem was solved by doing this.